# Government policy to incentivise third party investment

Tags: policy, environmental-policy

What reasonable policies could governments implement to incentivise NGOs and economic consulting firms to invest in national reserve conservation?

More specifically I want to know about how mining companies / economic advisory firms would be positively affected by such a policy. Telling them to go mine somewhere else for example is not a feasible policy to implement because the economy of the country would be negatively affected, as well as the company's economy.

Comment: "investment" means you invest resources **in expectation of receiving - presumably more - resources back at a later date**. What specific resources would be received from "national reserve conservation?" (short of selling tickets to the reserve; which doesn't generate much income)

Comment: You are talking about private national parks right? Carbon credits or some other anti-externals policy might qualify; some schemes you can get a reward for net plant growth. Sustainable logging requires 20-ish times as much land not being harvested as you can harvest in a year. Mining seems doubtful.

Comment: FYI, they just developed some sort of moss pseudo-tree that is supposedly better than 200+ real trees at cleaning out pollution/CO2. Tested in Germany I think.